# React+FastAPIでのCORSエラーの対処について

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webapi, fastapi

React+FastAPIでWebサイトを作成しました。FastAPI側では公式ドキュメントを読んでCORS対策しましたが、CORSエラーが出てデータをサーバーに送れません。何が原因なのでしょうか？
特徴
1.POST送信時のみエラーが出る。(GETメソッドでは起きない。)
2.ローカル環境(ReactとFastAPIは別ポート)ではPOST, GETとも問題なく動作する。
3.デプロイした環境でのみエラーが発生する。
コード
React

```
fetch('FastAPIのデプロイ先のURL', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    'data': data,
  })
});
```

FastAPI

```
app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'Reactのデプロイ先のURL'
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins = origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)

@app.post('/api/someapi')
async def result(item: dict = Body(...)):
    do_something(item['data'])
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

コードの詳細
フロントエンド側でボタンを押すと、FastAPIにデータを送信、DB操作をしたのち、無意味なresponseを返す。

エラーの詳細
Webブラウザのコンソールに

```
Access to fetch at 'FastAPIのURL' from origin 'ReactのURL' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

試したこと
1.return文で何も返さない、
2.JSONResponseヘッダーに直接'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'で許可を与える。

Comment: Fiddler などのキャプチャツールを使って要求・応答ヘッダーを調べてください。プリフライトに対処できてますか？